# Regular expression - Find the equivalence classes of Nerode theorem

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

> Find the equivalence classes of a nerode theorem and use equivalence
> classes to construct a reduced DFA for the following language:
> $^+(+)^*$

The answer:
$,^+,^+^∗+^+^+,(+)Σ^∗+⋅(+)Σ^∗$

I figured that the minimal base for the language is $a^+$ and for the $^+^∗+^+^+$ its just multiplying the expression with $(+)$ but I didn't figure where the $c^+$ came from. Isn't $c^*  = c^*?$

Now for the set and $(+)Σ^∗+⋅(+)Σ^∗$ I don't know what's the intuition for that and how they came up with it.

If im not wrong, epsilon is an equivalent set because it's competent of L

Comment: What is your question?  We require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  I am having a hard time determining what exactly your question is.